# Problemas con un input-group

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, bootstrap

Lo que pasa es que al digitar un documento que esta en la base de datos este se queda en un ciclo infinito no se porque

```js
$(document).on("focusout", "#ClienteId", function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim() != '') {
    cargarCliente($(this).text().trim(), $(this));
  } else {
    $("#ClienteNombre").val("Todos");
  }
});

function CargarCliente(id, input) {
  $.ajax({
    url: base_url() + "Busqueda/mostrarCliente",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      cod: id
    },
    success: function(respuesta) {
      var registro = JSON.parse(respuesta);

      if (registro.length > 0) {
        $("#ClienteId").html("");
        $("#ClienteNombre").val("");

        $("#ClienteId").text(registro[0].codigo).focusout();
        $("#ClienteNombre").val(registro[0].nombre).focusout();
      } else {
        var alerta = alertify.ajaxAlert(base_url() + "Busqueda/dataTable");
        input.closest(".inpur-group").find("input").val("").focusout();
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        alertify.notify('error', 'error', 5);
        input.closest(".input-group").find(".input-group-addon:eq(1)") text("");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.input-group-addon {
  width: 25%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label class="col-sm-2"><div class="row">Cliente :</div></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="ClienteId" contenteditable="true" style="background: rgb(255,255,255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" tabindex="10"></span>
      <input placeholder="Cliente" class="form-control input-sm" id="ClienteNombre" readonly="" type="text" tabindex="11">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas volviendo a llamar al evento que hace la llamada AJAX dentro de la respuesta de AJAX. `$("#ClienteId").text(registro[0].codigo).focusout();`

```
  if (registro.length > 0) {
    $("#ClienteId").html("");
    $("#ClienteNombre").val("");

    $("#ClienteId").text(registro[0].codigo).focusout();
    $("#ClienteNombre").val(registro[0].nombre).focusout();
  } else {
    var alerta = alertify.ajaxAlert(base_url() + "Busqueda/dataTable");
    input.closest(".inpur-group").find("input").val("").focusout();
  },
```

Comment: Gracias viejo me sirvio mucho eres un crack